# Linux mint 18.3 boot at black screen

Tags: linux-mint, boot, display-manager

After `apt upgrade`, I have problems with booting into the system.

Firstly, I was getting the message that Plymouth was missing and Bluetooth failed to initialize. After installing Plymouth theme I only get the Bluetooth error.

The picture is attached: How could I solve this issue?

[image]

I also have tried to install over other display managers like `sddm`, but I get black screen after grub.

I can get to the shell through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

The result of inxi:

[image]

Edit after reinstall of `lightdm`:

At boot:
[image]

`lightdm.service`:[image]

Comment: I will definitely switch, but now I need to boot into the system.

Comment: Lightdm was giving an error that it can not find /sbin/polymouthd and after reinstall of polymouth remain only error with Bluetooth but I couldn't boot either. Than I tried to install sddm and now I have clean black screen :)

Comment: I have updated my question with pictures results.

Comment: No it does not change anything.

Comment: Yes and I get result from  3rd image in my question

Comment: please post to your question `cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

Comment: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments:

```
cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

resulting in:

> ```
> No such file or directory
> ```

---

Just create the following file with your favorite editor, use nano, if unsure:

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

with contents:

```
[Seat:*]
allow-guest=false
```

and reboot.

---

Please run:

```
sudo apt-get install slick-greeter lightdm lightdm-settings apparmor
```

and reboot.

---

You can add an explicit directive to the new Slick Greeter by adding this line to the above config:

```
greeter-session=lightdm-slick-greeter
```

Comment: Same result with /sbin/plymouthd not found and /bin/plymouth: not found as in33rd picture

Comment: `plymouthd` is not important, does it let you log in now? If not, try to run again `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and then `startx`, what is the output.

Comment: @serj Please see the edit I just made.

Comment: So after installation and ddpkg-reconfigure I have run startx and gui appeared different one that I had but at least something but after every  restart again error with Plymouth not found and only after startx gui appeared

Comment: @serj So, case solved, or not yet?

Comment: No,  because after restart it does not  enter into gui

Comment: @serj So, you just type `startx` and the login screen appears now?

Comment: Not login but straight to home desktop